# How to fix encoding when execute java in php

Tags: java, php, character-encoding

front.php

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="backend.php">
        <input type="text" name="asdf">
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

backend.php

```php
if ( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ) {
    $test = [
        'test' => '한국어',
    ];
} else {
    $test = [
        'test' => $_POST['asdf']
    ];

}
$execRlt = exec('/usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=EUC-KR -classpath ... AA BB "'.$test['test'].'"');
var_dump($execRlt);
```

when execute this code in cli(php backend.php), korean is not broken but when receive from front.php korean is borken...
What part should i check?

Comment: I am just guessing, but I think utf-16 from java is being interpreted as either utf-8 or worse.  It is hard to say exactly where things are getting lost, but if it is on the php end, you need something like `mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8" , "UTF-16LE");` or `passthru('/usr/bin/java -D...')`

Comment: I already solve this issue using 'mb_detect_encoding' function

`$test['test'] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($test['php']), 'EUC-KR', $test['php']);`
Thank U :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question!!

```
if ( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' ) {
    $test = [
        'test' => '한국어',
    ];
} else {
    $test = [
        'test' => $_POST['asdf']
    ];
}
$test['test'] = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($test['php']), 'EUC-KR', $test['php']);
$execRlt = exec('/usr/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=EUC-KR -classpath ... AA BB "'.$test['test'].'"');
var_dump($execRlt);
```

Using 'mb_detect_encoding' function and convert encoding korean is not broken!